# Unit testing when developing a website?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

After learning about TDD and unit testing, I'm really looking to write tests when I code, preferably before I code because I see the benefits coding in Python. I'm developing a website, and I'm trying to write tests according to the requirements, but its proving more difficult than expected.

I can see the benefits of writing tests when you're producing a library of code with a public interface for others to use. Developing a website, where there is really not much logic, and mostly Reading and Writing against a database seems a little harder to unit test. Mostly, I have to create/edit/delete rows in the database.

I'm using a framework (Kohana 3 for php), so 99% of all the libraries and helpers that I'm going to be using have already been tested (hopefully), so what else is their to write tests for?

I'm mostly talking about scripting languages, not about CSS or HTML, I already know about cross-browser testing.

How much can you really test when developing a web site, and how should you go about it?

**Edit:**  Is the lack of activity on this question a sign? I understand that certain things MUST be tested, like security and the like, but how much can be written using unit tests and TDD is the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Which languages are you using? PHP?

Comment: Yes sir. That, and I'm using a framework to make life a little easier.

Comment: @user156814 "Is the lack of activity on this question proof that I'm right?"  In this case, what you're saying is so essentially wrong that it defies our ability to correct the misconceptions.  If your application does **anything**, then that thing it does is **testable**.  It makes no sense to claim that nothing testable is being done.  If that was true, why write code?

Comment: I wasn't saying that it wasnt testable, obviously there are ways to test for almost anything. I was asking how much would unit tests really help in this situation, unless I was writing a library of code for the site?

Comment: @user156814: I still don't understand your question.  "there are ways to test for almost anything"  That means there are unit tests for **everything**.  Every "feature" -- every line of code you wrote -- everything is testable as a discrete unit.  "how much would unit tests really help"?  I can't understand the question, since every unit of code you personally wrote must be tested.  How can you write software without testing every unit you wrote?  What are you asking?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, are "unit tests" the way to go when developing your run of the mill user interactive website? It seems that the majority of the code you write when developing a website would be better tested manually (or as SC Ghost said, using something like Selenium) like checking if links work, etc.

Comment: You _do_ want to test every unit (every line of code, etc.).  You do _not_ want to test every unit individually (where "units" overlap).  Some parts can be tested only manually. I think user156814's question is perfectly clear (since the last edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Developing a website, where there is really not much logic, and mostly Reading and Writing against a database seems a little harder to unit test. Mostly, I have to create/edit/delete rows in the database.

Not completely true.

You have data model processing.  Does the validation work?  Do the calculations on the reported rows from the  database work?

You have control, sequence and navigation among pages -- do the links work?  The test setup will provide a logged-in-user.  The test will (1) do a GET or a POST to fetch a page, then (2) confirm the page actually loaded and has the right stuff.

You have authorization -- who can do what? Each distinct test setup will provide a different logged-in-user.  The tests will (1) attempt a GET or POST to process a page.  Some tests will (2) confirm they got directed to error-response pages.  Some tests will (2) confitrm that the GET or POST worked.

You have content on the page -- what data was fetched?  The test setup will provide a logged-in-user.  The test will (1) do a GET or a POST to fetch a page, then (2) confirm the page actually loaded and has the right stuff.

Comment: I understand all that, but how much of that can be unit tested? i can see testing validation and authentication, but how do you test if links work using unit tests?

Comment: Maybe your use of "test unit" is confusing here. Everything needs to be tested, and a fundamental aspect of the 'net is that it's OS-agnostic. Get yerself a computer, load up your site, and see if it works. That's as good of a test unit as you'll need.

Comment: @eykanal: "load up your site, and see if it works".  Vague, unrepeatable and not automated.  If you wrote a unit of code for the site, you must test that unit of code -- in isolation.  It can't be any simpler.  If you wrote it, you must make a discrete unit of it and test it.  That's all.

Comment: I guess I was a little confused, i always thought unit tests were supposed to be independent of everything else (like DB's)... If I make a test to ensure that I get the right data out of the database, would'nt that depend on the right data being in the database in the first place?

Comment: @user166814: There are two ways to test DB access.  (1) Mock the database.  This is usually silly.  (2) Trust (and use) the database to test your application's proper access.  Totally mocking everything gets silly.  Using the database to test your application is typical.  Some argue that using the DB isn't "unit" testing, but they don't have a better term for it.  It's okay to be flexible.

Comment: @S.Lott: I wasn't familiar with the phrase "unit testing". If others are confused as I was, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066572/what-should-a-unit-be-when-unit-testing) has a good discussion of unit testing.

Comment: @S.Lott: I think the statement "mock the database is usually silly" is an overstatement. I don't do much web development, but I found that using something like a Repository to mediate the access to the database helps a lot: it gives you something to unit test, and you can test it with a mock so that you don't have to work against a real database.

Comment: @Mathias: I work with a test database populated with a test fixture all the time.  I don't mock the database; I use a test instance of the production database populated with test data.  Mocking the database is usually silly because it's often easier (and a better test) to use a test instance of the real database populated with test data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)? It allows you to automatically do almost anything in a web browser. For example, you could have it go through and click all of the links and make sure that they go to the correct url.

It works with multiple languages, including python and allows for testing in chrome, firefox, ie, and other browsers.

Comment: Just a dissenting opinion: http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2010/01/04/ui-test-automation-tools-are-snake-oil

Answer (score 0):

If your site contains many forms, how do you write them?  Do you write each view using plain HTML?  Or do you write your own form helpers that generate forms just the way *you* want them?  If you do that, you may find that unit-testing your form generators makes it easier to write them.

In general, if your program is mostly CRUD, look out for ways to automate CRUD management; write your own custom CRUD generator.  Which does not mean write the CRUD framework that will end all frameworks; that would be too much work.  Just write a generator for the small things you need for your current application.  TDD will help you there.